# chef how to give custom path for 'source' property

Tags: chef-infra

In chef, resource template has a property 'source', which picks up .erb only from templates directory.

Same thing for remote_directory property, where source location is COOKBOOK_NAME/files/default/

Is there a way to give a different location other than the pre-defined locations on chef workstation itself? For e.g. I want all the files including .erb that will be used by 'remote_directory' and 'template' resources under a new directory @ COOKBOOK/new_directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. All templates live under `templates/` and all files for `cookbook_file` and `remote_directory` live under `files/`. Side note: you don't need the `default/` anymore.

Comment: is it possible with custom resource?

Comment: No. More characters because SO doesn't like short answers.